# CMake error in CLion after updating CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

I am relatively new to coding in C++ and using CMake.  I have been writing code using CLion IDE on ubuntu 16.04.  I had written a library, with an older version of CMake (I believe it was version 3.4) which came bundled with CLion and for an unrelated reason needed to update to version 3.15.  Which I assume I must have done incorrectly.

When reloading Cmake projects that previously ran fine, I get the following error message:

```
Found Qt4: /usr/bin/qmake (found version "4.8.7") 
CMake Error at cmake-build-debug/_deps/eigen-src/cmake/language_support.cmake:33 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /home/majed/CLionProjects/TwoLink_manip/cmake-build-debug/language_tests/Fortran/CMakeLists.txt
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake-build-debug/_deps/eigen-src/test/CMakeLists.txt:19 (workaround_9220)
```

I have looked through a numeber of Cmake questions which I thought could be related to my issue but none of them seemed to address this specific issue.  I am not very familiar with the Cmake installation and setup and simply followed a youtube tutorial to install the latest release(cmake-3.15.5-Linux-x86_64.sh)from the cmake.org site.

I should point out that CMake does work when I run ROS packages from the terminal which is why I am apprehensive about re-installing everything. I am assuming the issue is related to where the cmake file is installed but not sure how to fix this issue with CLion. I would appreciate any and all suggestions.

I have also tried to export CMAKE_ROOT to the locaton of the new cmake folder but it doesn't really have any effect.

Comment: ***file failed to open for writing*** This seems to be your problem. You need to figure out where it's trying to write.

Comment: ***I assume I must have done incorrectly*** I would not assume that.

Comment: What does line 33 of `cmake-build-debug/_deps/eigen-src/cmake/language_support.cmake` look like?

Comment: line 33: ` file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/language_tests/${language}/CMakeLists.txt
    ${text}) `  ; @drescherjm - That does makes sense, I will try to find the directory of CMAKE_BINARY_DIR but not sure why this would have changed during the update.

Comment: You could put `message( STATUS CMAKE_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})` in the line before 33 and see what it prints.

Comment: I think I see what might be the problem, it's trying to write to a CMakeLists.txt in a read-only file